# Can I customise netdata not to alert me about 303 redirects?

Tags: web-server, monitoring, http-status-code

I use 303 codes (correctly, I believe) to redirect a user after they've submitted a form.  Unfortunately this means that a few times every day I get an alert from netdata along the lines of:

```
netdata notification
yoursite needs attention
web_log_yoursite.response_statuses
1m redirects = 21.1% 
the ratio of HTTP redirects (3xx except 304) over the last minute
```

I think I'd like to customise this behaviour so it becomes "(3xx except 304 or 303)", but I've no idea if this is possible or how I'd go about doing it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct of the purpose of `303 See Other`, just as described in [RFC 7231 6.4.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.4.4).

> This status code is applicable to any HTTP method.  It is primarily
> used to allow the output of a POST action to redirect the user agent
> to a selected resource, since doing so provides the information
> corresponding to the POST response in a form that can be separately
> identified, bookmarked, and cached, independent of the original
> request.

It seems your site is based on these POST requests and their redirects more than usual sites, thus exceeding the threshold defined in the `1m_redirects` template of NetData's `conf.d/health.d/web_log.conf`. Easiest way would be to increase the thresholds on lines `warn:` and `crit:`, as the "(3xx except 304)" in the configuration is merely an info text, not part of the logic used for matching log lines:

```
template: 1m_redirects
      on: web_log.response_statuses
families: *
  lookup: sum -1m unaligned of redirects
    calc: $this * 100 / $1m_requests
   units: %
   every: 10s
    warn: ($1m_requests > 120) ? ($this > (($status >= $WARNING ) ? (  1 ) : ( 20 )) ) : ( 0 )
    crit: ($1m_requests > 120) ? ($this > (($status == $CRITICAL) ? ( 20 ) : ( 30 )) ) : ( 0 )
   delay: up 2m down 15m multiplier 1.5 max 1h
    info: the ratio of HTTP redirects (3xx except 304) over the last minute
      to: webmaster
```

The special handling of `304 Not Modified` comes from the fact that it's truly comparable to `200 OK`:

> [RFC 7232, 4.1.](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232#section-4.1)  **304 Not Modified**
>
> The `304 (Not Modified)` status code indicates that a conditional GET
> or HEAD request has been received and would have resulted in a `200 (OK)`
> response if it were not for the fact that the condition
> evaluated to false.  In other words, there is no need for the server
> to transfer a representation of the target resource because the
> request indicates that the client, which made the request
> conditional, already has a valid representation; the server is
> therefore redirecting the client to make use of that stored
> representation as if it were the payload of a 200 (OK) response.

This definition is followed correctly in `python.d/web_log.chart.p` lines [746](https://github.com/firehol/netdata/blob/master/python.d/web_log.chart.py#L746)-761 and [906](https://github.com/firehol/netdata/blob/master/python.d/web_log.chart.py#L906)-921:

```
746/906:    def get_data_per_statuses(self, code):
747/907:        """
748/908:        :param code: str: response status code. Ex.: '202', '499'
749/909:        :return:
750/910:        """
751/911:        code_class = code[0]
752/912:        if code_class == '2' or code == '304' or code_class == '1':
753/913:            self.data['successful_requests'] += 1
754/914:        elif code_class == '3':
755/915:            self.data['redirects'] += 1
756/916:        elif code_class == '4':
757/917:            self.data['bad_requests'] += 1
758/918:        elif code_class == '5':
759/919:            self.data['server_errors'] += 1
760/920:        else:
761/921:            self.data['other_requests'] += 1
```

If you really wish to modify this to exclude `303`, then add `or code == '303'` to lines 752 & 912.

Comment: Thanks.  I have a photo-tagging part of my site which is why this arises.  If a photographer is on the site at a quiet time and doing some tagging, they can easily generate 20-30 303's per minute.

Comment: The `303` is the correct way to prevent re-uploading the same file. You can increase the thresholds or disable the template altogether, if you don't expect having real problems with redirects.

Comment: Not sure which file to edit when I have 3 copied of web_log.chart.py, so I've gone for all 3... `/opt/netdata/usr/libexec/netdata/python.d/web_log.chart.py`, `/usr/libexec/netdata/python.d/web_log.chart.py` and `/usr/src/netdata.git/python.d/web_log.chart.py`.  The only `.pyc` file resides with the first file I listed, so I assume that's the active one.